# "Class 'XMLWriter' not found" Error in php | php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm is missing

Tags: php, centos6, php5, packages, xml

I am getting this error in `PHP` in server `Fatal Error (E_ERROR): Class 'XMLWriter' not found` . we are using `Cent OS 6`

After exploring some sites, we found that we need to install [php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/php-dom(x86-64)). But the link is not working, I am not able to get this package. we are using `PHP 5.5.24`. We can not upgrade our PHP because of dependency with other products.Can we resolve this error without upgrading the `PHP`. Thanks !!!

**UPDATE:** we are using https://rollbar.com/ for error handing.

Answer (score 2):

`php55w-*` packages are webtatic packages and you don't need this if you don't use webtatics PHP installation.

Instead, use the relevant version for your installation of PHP. Normally, it should be just named `php-xml` or `php55-xml`.

If you indeed need the Webtatic version 5.5.24, please activate the `archive` repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` so you can access old, archived and **insecure** versions of packages.

If you don't have `/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic-archive.repo` in your system, it's likely you don't use Webtatic after all. Otherwise, you find the package directly here: http://archive.webtatic.com/yum/el6-archive/x86_64/php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I am trying to install relevant package which is php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm.  but can not find url link for it. please help

Comment: See my edit for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Sven , I will apply it and let you know if it resolves the issue. really appreciate your help.